# How to catch authenticated callback url using django regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

How to catch this callback url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/?oauth_token=pf9MsTxuB8&oauth_verifier=VBm3XUx
```

currently i have this

```
url(r'^callback/(?P<token>[^/]+)/$', 'twitter_auth', name= 'twitter_auth'),
```

but it catches `http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/oauth_token=pf9MsTxuB82zmdj2Y` without `?`

can you help out this ?

Comment: `?` indicates a `GET` URL parameter, which is not a part of the URL pattern. To fetch the `oauth_token` in the view, you would just do `request.GET.get('oauth_token')`, and your url pattern could just be `url(r'^callback/$', 'twitter_auth', name= 'twitter_auth'),`

Comment: oh... in my twitter app setting i given callback url like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/` after auth it redirect to above url with token and verfifier ...

Comment: @karthikr i am following [this](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) views.py there `url` redirect but after authenticated i ended up above url ..

Comment: Because that is the response from twitter. Adding the get parameters for you to habdle in the view. You are on the right path. Just update your url pattern

Comment: @karthikr that's worked. thanks for your help. i thought it only do with regex. hm .. looks like you told easy way ,,,

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in the title - if you have the answer now, either delete the question, answer it yourself or ask @karthikr to write it up.